# Making a webapp using Bottle

Tags: python, beginner, bottle

Here is a screenshot of my setup:

[image]

Here is the actual code:

```
#activate python virtualenv
activate_this = 'C:/Users/D/Dropbox/_mypyapp/learnbottle/learnbottle/scripts/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

#import dependencies
import os
from bottle import route, run, template

#this is what will become the page html
index_html = '''My First web app! By {{ author }}'''


@route('/:anything')
def something(anything = ''):
    return template(index_html, author = anything)
@route('/')
def index():
    return template(index_html, author = 'your name here')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080))
    run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = port, debut = True)
```

Couple things I should note:

- This is my first time using virtualenv
- This is the first time I am using git
- This is my first time writing any sort of web app or using a framework

I'm following along with a tutorial on realpython.com. The tutorial is written for a "Unix-based environment" so I had to do some things to get it working on Windows. Not sure if I should go the route of setting up a VM as it seems unnecessarily complicated.

So, am I making any newbie mistakes and is there anything I should do differently?

Answer (score 3):

Don't activate the virtualenv inside the script. If you do, the script won't be portable, it won't run on other computers, as that absolute path is specific to your computer. The `virtualenv` is part of the runtime execution environment, should not be part of the source code. Add a wrapper script that will activate the `virtualenv` and then run your app.

---

> ```
> @route('/:anything')
> def something(anything = ''):
>     return template(index_html, author = anything)
> ```

I don't know bottle, but it seems to me that the default value setting `anything = ''` is pointless, because the path `/` should not match this route.

---

[PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) dictates to put 2 empty lines before every global function declaration. So put 2 empty lines right before this code:

> ```
> @route('/')
> def index():
>     return template(index_html, author = 'your name here')
> ```

---

This looks like a typo:

> ```
> run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = port, debut = True)
> ```

You probably meant `debug` instead of "debut".